# custom sort in ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a very specific requirement. There is a three or four liner solution for the same. I need one liner solution.

Let's say i have an array like:

```
[["Andorra", "Andorra"], ["United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates"], 
 ["Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"], ["Antigua & Barbuda", "Antigua & Barbuda"], 
 ["Anguilla", "Anguilla"], ["Albania", "Albania"], ["Armenia", "Armenia"], 
 ["Angola", "Angola"]]
```

I want ["Anguilla", "Anguilla"] as my first element and else other in descending order.

Is there any way to achieve this ? (One liner if possible)

Comment: Why do you need a one-liner when you have a working solution? Post your solution, by the way.

Comment: @Sergio: When you have 3/4 lines of code to do a simple filter it probably means it's done with sloppy imperative code (each, inplace updates, ...). So no, no need to write one-lines, but yes, let's write concise functional code whenever possible.

Comment: btw, are the pairs in the array always the same? why?

Comment: Just replace all linebreaks with semicolons. Voilà: one-liner!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks guys for replying. The thing is i need a country list for my drop down list. To use Rails FormHelper i needed a list of countries which has US and CA on top of the list. To achieve this i don't want to have a separate helper method and crap. So, needed one liner.

Comment: @AashishP: those one-liners we posted are too heavy for a view (IMHO). I'd create a helper method.

Comment: -1 and close to vote. If the two elements in the pairs are always the same, then there is a code smell. Bad code. Furthermore, you have not told us so if that is the case. If they are not the same, you have not specified how they contribute in sorting. The question is not clear. Sorting by the first element? By the second? By the conjunction of the first and then the second? Or by the second and then the first?

Comment: Sorting by the conjunction of first and second.

Comment: @tokland This is what i require. That's why i kept in such a fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take advantage of the lexicographical order defined by arrays and sort the input by the desired criteria:

```
countries.sort_by { |s, s2| [s == "Anguilla" ? 1 : 0, s] }.reverse
#=> [["Anguilla", "Anguilla"], ..., ["Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"]]
```

@Sergio proposed using `Enumerable#sort` to avoid the `reverse`. IMO it's less declarative than the former, but for the record, that's how it may look:

```
countries.sort { |(s1, _), (s2, _)| s1 == "Anguilla" ? -1 : s2 <=> s1 }
#=> [["Anguilla", "Anguilla"], ..., ["Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"]]
```

Comment: Good one! Better than mine :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Thanks :-) It's a classic, using arrays to sort with lexicographical order. I'd like to remove that `reverse`, but I don't find a way, you cannot "negate" a string like an integer :-/

Comment: Check my answer for a "no reverse" solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's your one-liner:

```
countries = [["Andorra", "Andorra"], ["United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates"], ["Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"], ["Antigua & Barbuda", "Antigua & Barbuda"], ["Anguilla", "Anguilla"], ["Albania", "Albania"], ["Armenia", "Armenia"], ["Angola", "Angola"]]

custom_order = countries.partition{|arr| arr[0] == "Anguilla"}.map(&:sort).map(&:reverse).flatten(1)
custom_order # => [["Anguilla", "Anguilla"], ["United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates"], ["Armenia", "Armenia"], ["Antigua & Barbuda", "Antigua & Barbuda"], ["Angola", "Angola"], ["Andorra", "Andorra"], ["Albania", "Albania"], ["Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"]]
```

Here is an alternative solution:

```
custom_order = countries.sort do |c1, c2|
  if c1[0] == 'Anguilla'
    -1
  else
    c2 <=> c1
  end
end
```

Comment: @tokland: I think it does. "Anguilla" is less than any other element, and other elements we compare in a "backwards" manner. You can check the output :)

Comment: I removed the comment, I wrote it too fast :-) But I still have doubts about comparing Anguilla with itself and the block returning -1. Maybe `c1 == c2` for that branch?. Anyway, +1 :-)

Comment: @tokland: it's a block to `#sort`. It's *supposed* to return one of [-1, 0, 1] :)

Comment: you are right, let me think about it, but it should return 0 for that case.

Comment: @tokland: I don't think so. Why?

Comment: well, imagine `c1 = ["Anguilla", "Anguilla"]` and `c2 = ["Anguilla", "Anguilla"]`, does it make sense that the block returns -1? not sure. I'd expect to return 0.

Comment: Yeah, this logic assumes that there's only one Anguilla in the array. Which is guaranteed by the problem domain.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about the general case. I guess adding just another condition in this case would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

a bit primitive, but one line:

```
[["Anguilla", "Anguilla"]] << ([["Andorra", "Andorra"], ["United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates"], ["Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"], ["Antigua & Barbuda", "Antigua & Barbuda"], ["Anguilla", "Anguilla"], ["Albania", "Albania"], ["Armenia", "Armenia"], ["Angola", "Angola"]] - ["Anguilla", "Anguilla"]).sort{|a,b| b[0] <=> a[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[["Andorra", "Andorra"], ["United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates"], ["Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"], ["Antigua & Barbuda", "Antigua & Barbuda"], ["Anguilla", "Anguilla"], ["Albania", "Albania"], ["Armenia", "Armenia"], ["Angola", "Angola"]].sort{|a,b| b[0] <=> a[0]}.partition{|arr| arr[0] == "Anguilla"}
```

Comment: => [[["Anguilla", "Anguilla"]], [["United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates"], ["Armenia", "Armenia"], ["Antigua & Barbuda", "Antigua & Barbuda"], ["Angola", "Angola"], ["Andorra", "Andorra"], ["Albania", "Albania"], ["Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"]]] 
This is the output

Comment: That's what I mean. It doesn't quite match the desired output, does it?